# How do I reuse a RabbitMQ connection and channel outside of the "setup structure" with the amqp library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to build a simple node.js client using the amqp library, that opens a single connection and then a single channel to a RabbitMQ server. I want to reuse the same connection and channel to send multiple messages. The main problem is, that I don't want to write my entire code inside the callback function of the ceateChannel() function.

How do I reuse the channel outside of the callback function and make sure the callback function has finished before I use the channel?

I've tried both the callback way and the promise way but I can't make either of them work. When using the callback method I run into the described problem.

When using promises, I have the problem that I can't keep a reference of the connection and channel outside of the .then() function because the passed variables get destroyed after setting up the connection and channel.

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', (err, conn) => {

  if (err !== null) return console.warn(err);
  console.log('Created connection!');

  conn.createChannel((err, ch) => {

    if (err !== null) return console.warn(err);
    console.log('Created channel!');

    //this is where I would need to write the code that uses the variable "ch"
    //but I want to move the code outside of this structure, while making sure
    //this callback completes before I try using "ch"

  });
});
```

```
    amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then((conn) => {
      return conn.createChannel();
    }).then((ch) => {
      this.channel = ch;
      return ch.assertQueue('', {}).then((ok) => {
        return this.queueName = ok.queue;  
      });
    }).catch(console.warn);
```

Comment: why you don't use `async\await` ?

    const conn = await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost');
    const ch = await conn.createChannel();
    // after that you can use ch anywhere

Comment: Where exactly would i use that? I've tried but I don't exactly know how the best way would be.

Comment: I answered for better format of text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why you don't use `async\await` ?

```
const conn = await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost');
const ch = await conn.createChannel();
// after that you can use ch anywhere, don't forget to handle exceptions
```

Also if you use `amqplib`, don't forget to handle `close` and internal `error` events, for example like this:

```
conn.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('AMQP:Error:', err);
});
conn.on('close', () => {
    console.log("AMQP:Closed");
});
```

Comment: console output: "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: You should read how async\await works. They are async, but you can use await only inside of async function, so you could wrap that into async function.

Comment: Thank you I got it now!

Comment: Can you please share how you got this to work? I'm basically trying to initialize connection and channel for RabbitMQ on app startup, and then have utility functions that I can call to send messages or close the connection on the app shutdown. Ideally, I want to reuse the open connection/channel and not open new ones. I'm trying to export connection and channel (module.exports), but haven't figured it out yet.Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have the same question as @IraklisAlexopoulos, would appreciate any help

Comment: I can't use top level await

Answer (score 1):

Try with a class, like this:

**RabbitConnection.js**

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');

const RabbitSettings = {
    protocol: 'amqp',
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 5672,
    username: 'guest',
    password: 'guest',
    authMechanism: 'AMQPLAIN',
    vhost: '/',
    queue: 'test'
}

class RabbitConnection {

    constructor() {
        RabbitConnection.createConnection();
        this.connection = null;
        this.channel = null;
    }

    static getInstance() {
        if (!RabbitConnection.instance) {
            RabbitConnection.instance = new RabbitConnection();
        }
        return RabbitConnection.instance;
    }
    //create connection to rabbitmq
    static async createConnection() {
        try {
            this.connection = await amqp.connect(`${RabbitSettings.protocol}://${RabbitSettings.username}:${RabbitSettings.password}@${RabbitSettings.hostname}:${RabbitSettings.port}${RabbitSettings.vhost}`);
            this.channel = await this.connection.createChannel();
            this.channel.assertQueue(RabbitSettings.queue);
            console.log('Connection to RabbitMQ established');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    //send message to rabbitmq queue
    static async sendMessage(message, queueName) {
        try {
            let msg = await this.channel.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(message));
            console.log('Message sent to RabbitMQ');
            return msg;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = { RabbitConnection };
```

**ServerExpress.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { RabbitConnection } = require('./RabbitConnection');

const serverUp = () => {
    const app = express();
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        RabbitConnection.sendMessage('Hello World', 'test');
        res.send('Hello World!');
    });
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
    });
};

module.exports = { serverUp };
```

**index.js**

```
const { RabbitConnection } = require("./RabbitConnection");
const { serverUp } = require("./ServerExpress");

serverUp();
RabbitConnection.getInstance();
```